# getRequestCycle().urlFor not working in panel

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket

I need the URL for a component in wicket. When I use a page it works properly, but when using panel it does not work.

```
public final class ImageP extends Panel {

    public ImageP(String id) {
        super(id);
        List<Mapp> list = Mapp.loadall(); //load image from database
        final Mapp asr = list.get(0);
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource("image/jpeg", asr.getImage());
        Image image = new Image("img", resource);
        add(image);
        System.out.println(getRequestCycle().urlFor(image, IResourceListener.INTERFACE));
    }
}
```

This code does not work and throws an exception, but when I use page instead of panel `getRequestCycle().urlFor(image, IResourceListener.INTERFACE)` it works properly.

Comment: Which version of Wicket to do you use? In Wicket 6.0, there is no `urlFor` method which matches the signature you've used. Am I correct that you're using Wicket 1.5? Another question is: Do components on a page have URLs? AFAIK this only applies to pages and resources. If you want to get the URL of the resource, you have to pass a resource reference to `urlFor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you've got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Page found for component [Component id = img]
```

It's because RequestCycle object internally calls getPage() method of the component that's first parameter of the urlFor() method with the following signature:

```
urlFor(Component component, RequestListenerInterface interface)
```

In case of calling method urlFor() in the constructor of a panel it's impossible to get page of a panel's child because panel isn't attached to page yet. So Wicket throws "a nice exception".

To fix that problem you just can move your code to the onBeforeRender() method of the panel. Something like that:

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() {
    //
    // ... init resource ...
    //

    Image image = new Image("img", resource);
    addOrReplace(image);
    System.out.println(getRequestCycle().urlFor(image, IResourceListener.INTERFACE));

    super.onBeforeRender();
}
```

P.S. I also assume that you're using Wicket 1.4 or earlier because there's no RequestCycle.urlFor(component, listener) method in Wicket 1.5 and later. So I think neither your question nor my answer doesn't make sense in that case.